# SQL Inner join and Limit records

Tags: php, mysql

This is a simplification table structure that i have.

I have two tables.

```
TABLE 1

       ID        PTS        PID        TID
    ----------------------------------------
        1         3          1          22
        2         10         1          22
        3         5          1          22
        4         1          2          58
        5         0          2          58
        7         0          3          47
        8         5          3          47
        15        5          4          51
        15        3          4          51
        9         7          3          6
        10        0          1          8
        11        2          1          8
        12        4          5          1
        13        1          6          9
        14        2          5          12
        15        5          4          61
        15        6          4          61
        15        2          4          61
        16        0          7          100
        ect.      ect.       ect.       ect.


TABLE 2

      NAME       PID
    -------------------
      Jhon       1
      Peter      2
      Lisa       3
      Doe        4
      Joey       5
      Mike       6
      Debby      7
      ect.       ect.
```

Now i need to select the latest two PTS from each TID and match them whit PID row on table 2. and calculate the Average.

```
THE DESIRED OUTCOME

      NAME       AVG
    -------------------
      Jhon       4,25
      Peter      1,00
      Lisa       6,00
      Doe        4,00
      Joey       3,00
      Mike       1,00
      Debby      0,00
      ect.       ect.
```

Clarification: the PID row are relational. Multiple TIDs can have the same PID and TIDs can have multiple PTS. I am using PDO socket.

At the time my query is:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT IFNULL(AVG(pts), 0) AS P, TA1.PID AS TA1PID, name AS N FROM ".
                    "table1 TA1 LEFT JOIN table2 TA2 ON TA1.PID = TA2.PID ".
                    "GROUP BY name, TA2.PID ".
                    "ORDER BY TA1.id DESC");
```

But this calculates all the points(PTS) from TID. but i would like to only calculate the Two latest points(PTS) per TID. I have tried different queries the whole day but i cant figure it out. I am pretty new to SQL I managed to get one example working but with pure PHP and its not pretty :D

**sqlFiddle:** [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/1)

The problem is that it calculates all the TID points in Average. It only should calculate the two last entries per TID

I hope this is a clear question. I have tried my best to explain my problem. If any questions please ask. I have read other similar problems than mine here on Stackoverflow but i could not modify them to work for me.

Comment: Please consider setting up a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ Can you post what you expect the outcome to look like?

Comment: have you tried "limit 2" at the end of your query?

Comment: @subas_poudel that won't work. That would give two records Doe and Jhon. It would also be the average of all of Doe and Jhon's records rather than just their last two

Comment: I am making a sqlfiddle. will take some time i am quite new to sql

Comment: Here is sqlFiddle. [sqlFiddle]( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/1) The problem is that it calculates all the TID points in Average. It only should calculate the two last entries per TID.

Comment: JOIN on a subquery with LIMIT 2,it`s not clear to me how you get the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only the most recent 2 rows from the first table using this query

```
select t1.id, t1.pts, t1.pid, t1.tid
from table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t2.id >= t1.id and t1.tid = t2.tid
group by t1.id
having count(*) <= 2
```

and plug it into your original query instead of table 1

```
SELECT IFNULL(AVG(pts), 0) AS AVG, TA1.PID AS 
Table1_ID, name AS Name FROM
(
    select t1.id, t1.pts, t1.pid, t1.tid
    from table1 t1
    join table1 t2 on t2.id >= t1.id and t1.tid = t2.tid
    group by t1.id
    having count(*) <= 2
)
TA1 LEFT JOIN table2 TA2 ON TA1.PID = TA2.PID
      GROUP BY name, TA2.PID
      ORDER BY TA1.id DESC
```

Comment: Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/11) for your answer. It's worth noting that this answer (joining on an inequality) works on all DBs

Answer (score 1):

Group Per N are pretty easy in Most DBs. Just use ROW_NUMBER. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have them so we must simulate it

```
SELECT name, 
       Avg(PTS) 
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
                  CASE 
                    WHEN @previousPID IS NULL 
                          OR @previousTID IS NULL 
                          OR ( @previousPID = ORDERED.pid 
                          AND @previousTID = ORDERED.tid )
                          THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
                    ELSE @rownum := 1 
                  end rn, 
                   @previousPID := ORDERED.pid ,
                   @previousTID := ORDERED.tid
           FROM   (SELECT t2.name, 
                          t2.pid, 
                          t1.id, 
                          t1.tid ,
                          t1.Pts

                   FROM   table2 t2 
                          INNER JOIN table1 t1 
                                  ON T2.pid = t1.pid 
                   ORDER  BY t1.pid, 
                             t1.tid,
                             t1.id DESC)ORDERED, 
                  (SELECT @rownum := 0, 
                          @previousPID := NULL,
                          @previousTID := NULL) t) CTE 
WHERE  CTE.rn <= 2 
GROUP  BY name
```

Which has the following [Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/14/0)

```
|      NAME | AVG(PTS) |
|-----------|----------|
|       Doe |        4 |
|      Jhon |     4.25 |
|      Joey |        3 |
|      Lisa |        4 |
|      Mike |        1 |
| No points |        0 |
|     Peter |      0.5 |
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/14)

Looking at the [intermediate results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb622a/15/0) may help to understand how the CASE statements generate the rownumbers

```
|      NAME | PID | ID | TID | PTS | @ROWNUM := 0 | @PREVIOUSPID := NULL | @PREVIOUSTID := NULL | RN | @PREVIOUSPID := ORDERED.PID | @PREVIOUSTID := ORDERED.TID |
|-----------|-----|----|-----|-----|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|----|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
|      Jhon |   1 |  3 |  22 |   5 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           1 |                          22 |
|      Jhon |   1 |  2 |  22 |  10 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           1 |                          22 |
|      Jhon |   1 |  1 |  22 |   3 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  3 |                           1 |                          22 |
|      Jhon |   1 | 12 |   8 |   2 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           1 |                           8 |
|      Jhon |   1 | 11 |   8 |   0 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           1 |                           8 |
|     Peter |   2 |  5 |  58 |   0 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           2 |                          58 |
|     Peter |   2 |  4 |  58 |   1 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           2 |                          58 |
|      Lisa |   3 |  7 |  47 |   5 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           3 |                          47 |
|      Lisa |   3 |  6 |  47 |   0 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           3 |                          47 |
|      Lisa |   3 | 10 |   6 |   7 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           3 |                           6 |
|       Doe |   4 |  9 |  51 |   3 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           4 |                          51 |
|       Doe |   4 |  8 |  51 |   5 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           4 |                          51 |
|       Doe |   4 | 19 |  61 |   2 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           4 |                          61 |
|       Doe |   4 | 17 |  61 |   6 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  2 |                           4 |                          61 |
|       Doe |   4 | 16 |  61 |   5 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  3 |                           4 |                          61 |
|      Joey |   5 | 13 |   1 |   4 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           5 |                           1 |
|      Joey |   5 | 15 |  12 |   2 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           5 |                          12 |
|      Mike |   6 | 14 |   9 |   1 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           6 |                           9 |
| No points |   7 | 18 | 100 |   0 |            0 |               (null) |               (null) |  1 |                           7 |                         100 |
```

Comment: OP needs **Two latest points(PTS) per TID** which obviously will be in same pid group your query will give 2 latest records per pid which is not OP wanted

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Ah I see I didn't read it completely. I'll fix it

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I finally understood what the OP was after.